# Short, Opinionated Answers

Tags: discussion

Looking through some of the questions and answers already on the site there are a few questions where the answers given are simply short 1-line answers based on the answer-ers experience. This is possibly best demonstrated [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/155/is-there-a-web-application-that-allows-you-to-set-up-a-wiki-in-10-minutes), where the answers don't cover more than one service, and is simply a list of what people currently use - rather than a (more) comprehensive answer covering possibly multiple services and  advantages and disadvantages.

Now it appears to me that a more comprehensive answer would be better for a question such as the one I linked to above - but I guess what I'm asking is: "Are these short answers based solely on users experiences what the WA site is looking for/acceptable?"

As an additional note, the [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) doesn't actually include any information about what sort of answers are useful and is something that possibly needs 'nailing down'

Comment: About your "additional note:" that is by design. *You* guys are supposed to be designing this site. That's what meta is for: to be having these discussions.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of this site has changed. At this time, asking for web app recommendations is offtopic. See [Make all recommendation questions out of scope and off topic, regardless of research](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2595/88163)

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem with these "list of X" questions. It's a backhanded way of conducting a poll: "what are you using" or "what is your favorite {whatever}?"

They're not strictly off topic or even subjective but there also not exactly the type of questions we are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

For questions like the one you linked to, I think there are advantages to only listing one service per answer. It allows people to vote for each web app separately instead of the whole collection. Hopefully, the combination of answers will provide a more comprehensive list of services available, sorted by popularity (among users who read the question and voted).

Comment: You're right, but then the question/answers should at least be CW.