# So where do we discuss/vote on the site's Name/URL/style, etc?

Tags: discussion

So other than "committing" to the site, and suggesting good "on-topic" and "off-topic" questions, where is the discussion/voting about the *rest* of what goes into making WebApps.Stackexchange?

- Official site name
- Site URL
- Style and colors
- Official "purpose statement" and FAQ contents

Did I miss this somewhere on Area51? Were these things already decided by the "powers-that-be"?

Answer (score 6):

The FAQ [is left up to us](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/whats-the-difference-between-a-website-and-a-web-app) to [self-organize](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/short-opinionated-answers) on.

The 'Official Site Name', 'Url' will be picked by the community (us) when we get closer to that stage.  The site has to be able to make it out of beta before they spend the time and money on that.

With regards the style and colors, I imagine that they'll have a graphic designer do a few layouts (or outsource it?) and we'll pick from the choices.

Answer (score 2):

That should definitely be done **here**. So you have the right idea!

We haven't established exactly how this stuff will work, so feel free to have a go at it.. we can decide together how we want it to work and try some experiments. That's the "advantage" of being first. :)