# Clarify "Ask Question" placeholder text

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

The current placeholder text in the "Ask Question" form title reads:

> What's your web applications question? Be specific.

I think this can be clarified to (maybe) stop or slow down users who are new to the site and have the mistaken idea that the site is for web application development questions.

Perhaps it could be changed to something like:

> What's your web applications utilization question? Be specific.

(h/t [Ramon Melo](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4139/354))

Or maybe:

> What's your question about using a web application? Be specific.

Or maybe:

> What's your web applications usage (not programming) question? Be specific.

I think something (anything!) that does a bit more to emphasize that the site is not for programming questions would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested / willing to update this feature request, (not about programming / developing web apps) checkout SpencerG's  answer (April 6, 2023) to

[The guidance in the "Step 1: Draft your question" box on the Ask Question page should be customized](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4569/88163)

And the following related Announcement in Meta Stack Exchange

- [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691)
- [What site-specific changes can be made to the Ask Question page to help askers on that site write better questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/289691)

## Similar feature-request from sister sites

### Ask Ubuntu Meta

- [Can we warn new users that questions about Kali Linux, Pop OS and so on are off topic when they attempt to ask a new question?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19447/1163497)