# Are storefront sites like eBay, Apple App Store and Amazon considered to be "web applications"?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are storefront sites like eBay, Apple App Store and Amazon considered to be "web applications"?

The current help page is pretty vague, it just defines a "web application" as "a website which behaves like an application" without really defining what an "application" is. The [Wikipedia description of "application software"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) tends to describe it as doing complicated or constructive tasks such as a word processor, a spreadsheet, an accounting application. In the old days storefronts were generally considered to fall into the category of [E-commerce portals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-commerce), not applications, however this site may want to make a broader definition of "application" that includes relatively simple functionality. For example, a hotel web site that allows a visitor to book a reservation. Is that an "application"? What about a club web site that has a form that allows a person to enter their email address to be added to a mailing list. Is that considered to be an "application" even though all the user is doing is entering an email address and pressing enter?

In any case, I would suggest that some kind of definition of what constitutes an "application" for the purpose of this stack exchange should be included on the help page.

Comment: Votes work differently on [meta-tag:discussion] and [meta-tag:feature-request]. On the former means helpful/unhelpful while on the later means agreement/disagreement.As a feature request, IMHO, it's too vague so will remove the corresponding tag.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [What's the difference between a website and a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/354) I disagree with the accepted answer but, as it is the accepted answer, has more or less guided what's allowed here since the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

Yes they are, but only those questions about using the web front app.  Questions about installable apps are off-topic.

## Extended answer

### Current tags

- [amazon](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) 152 questions
- [ebay](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebay) 53 questions
- Apple App Store?

### Some sort of definition

What about this?

> A *web application* is something that is reachable through an URL by using a web browser and that includes features that have certain use complexity.

### Regarding the examples

> For example, a hotel web site that allows a visitor to book a reservation. Is that an "application"?

This could be on-topic if the question is about using the the hotel web site but will be off-topic if it's asking customer servicer support.

> What about a club web site that has a form that allows a person to enter their email address to be added to a mailing list. Is that considered to be an "application" even though all the user is doing is entering an email address and pressing enter?

I don't see what kind of question could be done about using the club web site other than customer service support questions.

**Related Q&A**

- [Is your question about **using** web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4569/88163)
- [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)