# Is it allowed to ask "how to" question about an online shopping website*?

Tags: support

I have a question about banggood.com, can I ask it on webapps? If so why?

I don't find this information.

(It required more characters, so I write more: yes I did make sure that it completely describes my problem - including what I have already tried - and is written using proper grammar. ).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are storefront sites like eBay, Apple App Store and Amazon considered to be "web applications"?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/are-storefront-sites-like-ebay-apple-app-store-and-amazon-considered-to-be-web)